# jquery animate height bouncing

Tags: jquery, css, height, jquery-animate, slide

i made a script that dynamically loads content into a div and whenever the content makes the div's height bigger or smaller it animates the height to the actual height.

The problem is that it doesn't only slide up/down it always slides a bit up and then down to the desired height.

I'd like to make it slide directly at the desired height without the "bouncing".

Here's part of the script:
main_content.html(html);

```js
main_content.css("height", "auto");
var newContentHeight = main_content.height();
loader_div.hide();
main_content.height(prevContentHeight);
main_content.fadeIn("fast", function() {
    main_content.animate({
        "height": newContentHeight
        }, 300);
    });
```

The script works, the only problem is that the animation doesn't slide the div up or down to the desired height, it always slides it a bit up and then down to the desired height.

Is it some kind of wanted animation when using animate height or is there something wrong?
Thanks

edit: console logging newContentHeight(the final height of the div) it looks like it gathers 2 heights, then the animate first goes to one of them and then to the other one that's why it looks like bouncing. Working on it.

edit2: yes the problem is definitely there, i cleaned up all the code and everything works except that i get 2 attributes from newContentHeight using console.log it looks like the content div that is hidden has 2 heights and those 2 heights are passed to the .animate that's why it first goes up and then down...
Kinda strange

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @Mateusz W i made a jsfiddle yesterday but forgot to save it, couldn't replicate the whole site and replicating the script worked just fine then it wouldn't have helped.
Worked a bit on it and the problem is that i try to get the height of the div while it's hidden and it doesn't get it, if i add `main_content.css({display: "block"});` into the above code and THEN get the height of the div, it gets the right height. But i need it to be hidden.
Using an hack didn't work either(showing it with -9999px margin get the height and hiding it again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't solve the problem, i modified the script below and now everything works like it should.
http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/
It has the exact animation i was looking for(except for a couple of steps easily implementable).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not the script, but the system running the script. Replace the time to a bit slower

```
main_content.animate({
"height": newContentHeight
}, 3000);
```